# What is wrong when using array of array type with possible range (0 to 0)?

Tags: arrays, syntax, vhdl

I don't really understand what is wrong :

I have an unconstrained type

```
type int_matrix_type is array (natural range <>, natural range <>) of integer;
```

that I'm using to create different sizes of matrices, even I want a matrix with the range `(0 to 1, 0 to 0)` which I consider will give a matrix of 2 lines and 1 column (right?), like in this example `signal example2_matrix` :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity toto is
    port (
        clk : in std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture test of toto is

    -- type declaration
    type int_matrix_type is array (natural range <> ,natural range <>) of integer;
    -- examples of matrix signals
    signal example1_matrix : int_matrix_type (0 to 1, 0 to 1) 
    := ((0, 1),
        (2, 3)
        );
    signal example2_matrix : int_matrix_type (0 to 1, 0 to 0)
    := ((0), -- here line 20
        (2)  --      line 21
        );  
        
begin

end test;
```

But when I compile, Quartus returns errors

[image]

So what is wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your line 20 and 21 aggregates are not compatible with the subtype of example2_matrix.  `signal example2_matrix : int_matrix_type (0 to 1, 0 to 0) := (0 => (0 => 0),1 => (0 => 1));` Note the second dimension (the subaggregates have only one element while the aggregate of the type has two. This can also be positional `signal example2_matrix : int_matrix_type (0 to 1, 0 to 0)  := ((0 => 0),(0 => 1));` where the sub aggregate has a single element and must use named association (the name can be `others`).

Comment: The semantic rule is found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3 Aggregates, 9.3.3.1 General "Aggregates containing a single element association shall always be specified using named association in order to distinguish them from parenthesized expressions." The rest is poor error messages.

Comment: Duplicate of [VHDL asignment to an array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176962/vhdl-assignment-to-an-array-type). Also see [2D Unconstrained Nx1 Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359413/2d-unconstrained-nx1-array/35362198).

Answer (score 1):

Solutions were given in the comments under the main post. So I'm just rewritting here a clear solution for others. I quote :

@user16145658

> The semantic rule is found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3 Aggregates, 9.3.3.1 General "Aggregates containing a single element association shall always be specified using named association in order to distinguish them from parenthesized expressions."

which means that my code should look more like :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity toto is
    port (
        clk : in std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture test of toto is

    -- type declaration
    type int_matrix_type is array (natural range <> ,natural range <>) of integer;
    -- examples of matrix signals
    signal example1_matrix : int_matrix_type (0 to 1, 0 to 1) 
    := ((0, 1),
         (2, 3)
        );
    -- this not ok
    --signal example2_matrix : int_matrix_type (0 to 1, 0 to 0)
    --:= ((0), -- here line 20
    --    (2)  --      line 21
    --    ); 
    -- this ok
    signal example2_matrix : int_matrix_type (0 to 1, 0 to 0) 
    := (0 => (0 => 0),
        1 => (0 => 1)); 
    -- or
    signal example2bis_matrix : int_matrix_type (0 to 1, 0 to 0)  
    := ((0 => 0),
        (0 => 1));
         
begin

end test;
```

Hope it will help others !